# How can I emit to a single client with socket.io (rather than everyone)

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Combing through the documentation but no luck. I'm trying to emit to a single client/user rather than everyone.

I read several other questions about this, most have no answer or point to older solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

The following works but emits to everyone on the site rather than the individual user...

SERVER:

```
//Socket.io
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = cryptonize.encrypt(req.body.email);
    const password = cryptonize.encrypt(req.body.password);
    io.emit('login success', email, password);
});
```

CLIENT:

```
const socket = io();
socket.on('login success', (user, token, auth) => {
    console.log(`user:${user}, password:${password});
});
```

I've tried "socket.emit" as mentioned in the socket.io cheat sheet, but it's coming back as undefined on the server. Probably something really simple I'm missing, just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, for anyone else trying to figure this out.

SERVER:

```
//Socket.io
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = cryptonize.encrypt(req.body.email);
    const password = cryptonize.encrypt(req.body.password);
    const socketid = req.query.socket;

    io.sockets.connected[socketid].emit('login success', email, password);
});
```

CLIENT:

```
const socket = io();
let socketid;
socket.on('connect', () =>  socketid = socket.io.engine.id);
```

CLIENT cont..
Then I just added a "socketid" query to my posts as they're generated.

```
//XHR Setup
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let response, status, readyState;
xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) response = xhr.response;
};

//XHR POST
const post = ({ url, callback, data }) => {
    xhr.open('POST', `${url}&socketid=${socketid}`, true), xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json'), xhr.send(data);
    if (callback) callback();     
    console.log(`${url}&socketid=${socketid}`);   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is the intended use of socket.io.

In your case, a simple `res.end(...)` will do (at least based on what you showed us).

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = cryptonize.encrypt(req.body.email);
    const password = cryptonize.encrypt(req.body.password);
    res.end(/* data */);
});
```

Read the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) about `res.end()`.

If you really need to emit to a single socket, you need more work:

1. Use [socket.io's rooms or namespace](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).
2. Get [target socket's id](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-id).
3. Emit using the socket id.

Here's an example using default namespace:

*Server*

```
const IO = require('socket.io');
const io = IO(server);

// Default namespace is '/'
const namespacedIO = io.of('/');

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('send', data => {
        const targetSocket = namespacedIO.connected[data.socketID];
        targetSocket.emit('received', data.value);
    });
});
```

*Client*

```
const socket = io();

submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('send', {
        socketID: socket.id,  // IMPORTANT: to get the source socket ID
        value: input.value
    });
})

socket.on('received', function(data){
    console.log(`Data "${data}" is received at server.'`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, some useful info there I'll be using. Unfortunately, res.end() doesn't work for my particular use case. I found a way to achieve what I'm going for. I'll post so others can find it too.